# vim string substitution

Tags: vim, substitution

I want to substitute all `cygdrive/e` with `cygdrive/d` using vim. But I can't get the matching pattern correctly. Here is my command:

```
s/cygdrive\/e/cygdrive\/d/g
```

it doesn't work. Can anybody show me what is wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly is it that it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search pattern and replacement string look fine.

Make sure you are in `ex` mode when you try it.

So press `ESC`, then `:` and then

```
%s/cygdrive\/e/cygdrive\/d/g
```

But if you want all he replacements in just the current line you can do:

```
s/cygdrive\/e/cygdrive\/d/g
```

Answer (score 3):

vim allows you to specify the delimiter.. (First character after s is the delimiter)

```
s/cygdrive\/e/cygdrive\/d/g
```

using line range argument .. and # as delimiter

```
ESC:
:1,$    s#/cygdrive/e#/cygdrive/d#g
```

Comment: this is cool. Is the # symbol only understood by vim or vi also?

Comment: Whatever character that follows the substitute command is understood as the delimiter by vi, vim, sed, etc.

Answer (score -2):

You have to escape the special character
like this
s/cygdrive\/e/cygdrive\/d/g